# Soundcloud widget not working in ie10

Tags: html, widget, internet-explorer-10, soundcloud

I have embedded a Soundcloud HTML 5 widget in a webpage designed in Dreamweaver, and it is part of an accordeon spry. Currently, it does not work under ie10. I simply cannot play the widget. I have looked for solutions on this forum and the only thread that mentions this does not solve the issue.

The Widget loads up and displays okay, but once there I simply cannot play anything. None of the play buttons work and I cannot select any of the songs. Is ie10 recognizing the widget as a threat and therefore blocking access?

I can, however, click on the icons and be taken to the playslist itself in the soundcloud website.

All is fine in Chrome and Opera...

What further information would you like from me that would be useful?

Your thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a demo for us to test?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I am having the same issue.  I'm using IE 10 on Windows 7.  Everything is freshly installed and I haven't changed any of the default settings.  The error I'm seeing in the IE console is this:

SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object 
widget-950b2e7e.js, line 20 character 145

Comment: @LarryFoulkrod Do you have an online demo I can check out?